# Tab widget with icon on left of text. Place tabs on bottom instead of top of screen.

Tags: android, tabs

I'm building a tab activity and but I don't want the tab text to appear below the icon. Is there any XML property to define this behavior?
On the other hand, how can I place tabs in the bottom of the screen instead of the top?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a few things.  First off you need to find yourself an example of a TabHost using a custom TabHost layout like this. Notice the Relative layout and the use of android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

One example is this:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Be careful about using examples like this "extends TabActivity  implements TabContentFactory"  .I am not sure where you set the layout in this case. It inflates its own as you call addTab().

```
<!--  Tab items -->

</TabHost>
```